# Refreshing of image upon OnVScroll

Tags: c++, mfc, scroll

I am trying to display a large data set into a graph. Unfortunately this causes flickering as `OnPaint()` is called multiple times during any update. And at the same time I do not need this graph to be updated constantly; only once upon loading the program is sufficient.

I found a way to solve it by overriding the `OnEraseBkgnd()` to return 1 everytime something updates. However, a side effect of this is that when I do a vertical scrolling, this graph will get "cut off" if I scroll too far.

Bringing the scroll back up I will end up with a cut-off graph, which does not repaint (because I do not redraw the graph in `OnPaint()` anymore).

In essence, what I am looking for, is a method to repaint the graph, if and only if it gets "cut off", due to the scrolling view.

Thanks!

Comment: I would try rendering the graph to an off-screen bitmap (memory DC); that way all you have to do in `WM_PAINT` is blit it to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The MFC sample in MSDN named DRAWCLI is an example program that includes image scrolling and using an off-screen bitmap to eliminate flicker. It works very well.

Answer (score 0):

As Jonathan Potter recommended, memory DC is way to go.

When your view becomes invalid, then message handler sends WM_PAINT to your OnPaint handler function, which will call OnDraw member function after creating DC object.

You use your memory DC in OnDraw function.

There is nice code example of memory DC, which is really easy to implement [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33/Flicker-Free-Drawing-In-MFC).